# Error with Traefik on Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, traefik, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to deploy Traefik as an ingress controller on my GKE cluster.
It's a basic cluster with 3 nodes.

I'm used to deploy Traefik using manifest on a Kubernetes cluster deployed by Kubespray, but we are migrating some of our infrastructures to GCP.

So I tried to deploy Traefik using the [community helm chart](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/traefik) with the following configuration:

```
image: traefik
imageTag: 1.6.2

serviceType: LoadBalancer
loadBalancerIP: X.X.X.X

kubernetes:
  ingressClass: traefik

ssl:
  enabled: false
  enforced: false
  insecureSkipVerify: false

acme:
  enabled: false
  email: hello@mydomain.com
  staging: true
  logging: false
  challengeType: http-01

dashboard:
  enabled: true
  domain: traefik.mydomain.com
  ingress:
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik

gzip:
  enabled: true
accessLogs:
  enabled: true
  format: common
```

And then launch it with the following command:

```
helm install --namespace kube-system --name traefik --values values.yaml stable/traefik
```

All is well deployed on my K8S cluster, except the dashboard-ingress with the following error:

```
kevin@MBP-de-Kevin ~/W/g/s/traefik> kubectl describe ingress traefik-dashboard -n kube-system
Name:             traefik-dashboard
Namespace:        kube-system
Address:
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.20.2.6:8080)
Rules:
  Host                      Path  Backends
  ----                      ----  --------
  traefik.mydomain.com
                               traefik-dashboard:80 (10.20.1.14:8080)
Annotations:
Events:
  Type     Reason  Age   From                     Message
  ----     ------  ----  ----                     -------
  Warning  Sync    4m    loadbalancer-controller  googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'namedPorts[2].port': '0'. Must be greater than or equal to 1, invalid
```

Any idea where is my error?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi `traefik-dashboard:80 (10.20.1.14:8080)` Why is there two different Port?

Answer (score 2):

```
Invalid value for field 'namedPorts[0].port': '0'
```

This error happens when the `Service` that's being used by GKE Ingress is of type `ClusterIP` (and not `NodePort`). GKE Ingress requires backing Services to be of type NodePort.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! Yes I think this is related to the traefik dashboard handle by the GKE ingress. But this is weird because I tried to specify the ingress class with the following annotation:  `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik`
Any idea on why the ingress is ignoring the annotation?

Comment: Traefik should definitely respect that annotation (and GKE's Ingress controller should definitely ignore such Ingresses then). Could you please share your dashboard's Ingress spec (in case this is still relevant to you)?

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when the service that the ingress controller expects does not exists. (maybe it was accidentally deleted)

nginx-ingress-controller on gke works with services exposed as clusterIP

Answer (score 0):

you have forgotten to enable rbac.

Sample bellow worked fine

```
serviceType: LoadBalancer
rbac:
  enabled: true
dashboard:
  enabled: true
  domain: dash.example.com
  ingress:
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
kubernetes:
  ingressClass: traefik
  namespaces:
    - default
    - kube-system
```